# isReachable method

Tags: java, network-programming

I am using isReachable() method and I am trying to reach a pc on a local network from my android mobile phone. It returns false when firewall on pc is on, and it returns true when firewall is off. I tried to create a new rule to allow port 7 (echo) on firewall. But it didn't work. Can any one help me how to allow isReachable() to returns true when firewall is on ?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29) says that:

> A typical implementation will use ICMP ECHO REQUESTs if the privilege
>   can be obtained, otherwise it will try to establish a TCP connection
>   on port 7 (Echo) of the destination host.

Then you need to be sure that ICMP ECHO is allowed by your firewall.

Also, if you have a service running on the other PC, you could just attempt to open a `Socket` despite of the value returned by `isReachable`.

Comment: ICMP is also allowed in the firewall settings, although, isReachable is blocked by the firewall !

Comment: The *actual* implementation doesn't use ICMP at all.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't use it at all. Just try to connect in the normal way, and handle the failures accordingly. isReachable doesn't add anything useful to that.